# How to install grunt on windows 8

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to install grunt on a windows 8 machine (I'm normally mac)

I have node, ruby installed - if I test with ruby -v and node -v I get the version numbers.

I have installed grunt with

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

I get a long list of npm http installs.

If then test with grunt -v I get

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `open': No such file or directory - repos (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `entries'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/project.rb:18:in `generate_files'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:13:in `block in <class:Server>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1402:in `configure'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:13:in `<class:Server>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:2:in `<module:Grunt>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/lib/grunt/server.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/grunt-0.0.6/bin/grunt:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/grun
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a Ruby gem installed named grunt. Run `gem uninstall grunt`, which would uninstall the grunt gem. `grunt -v` is not the correct command.

If you have `Gruntfile.js` in your current working directory, on the command line just execute  the below command, which will execute the default grunt tasks.

```
grunt
```